# WiX installer project: CefSharp.Core.dll could not be loaded, file not found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, wix, cefsharp

I am working on a windows application on c# visual studio, i have set up a WiX project for the installer and have added CefSharp, CefSharp.Core, CefSharp.Wpf references to it also.

However, upon building, it throws an error that the extension

> **'..\packages\CefSharp.Common.57.0.0\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.Core.dll' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load
> file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
> specified module could not be found.  InstallProj candle.exe  0**

The file exists in that directory but for some reason it cannot be loaded. I have tried referencing both x64 and x86 but to no avail. But when I unload the WiX project and build, the error does not occur build successfully.

I have browsed a lot of similar questions where this dll could not be loaded but none helped fix my issue. I have tried reloading the dependencies

#### Edit:

I tried removing the references and uninstalling the CefSharp.Common and CefSharp.Wpf packages from **InstallProj**. It still tries to load the dll with the same error.

Comment: What project are you try to build?

Comment: it's a windows application project that has a WiX project for the msi installer

Comment: The errors comes during you build WIX project?

Comment: precisely, when i unload the wix project the error does not occur

Comment: Which one is your main project between three this CefSharp, CefSharp.Core, CefSharp.Wpf.

Comment: these three are the dependencies. My solution has a WiX installer project and a main project that has the 3 dependencies. The issue is in the WiX project

Comment: Any errors when you open  CefSharp.Core.dll from the include directory with depends.exe?

Comment: @BrianSutherland Not quite sure I follow you

Comment: So I  was using WiX toolset v4.0 for this.I had to make another installer project using WiX toolset v3.11 and that seemed to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, I downgraded from WiX toolset v4.0 to v3.11 and fixed it in this case